# Adobe Flash project writing data to .csv file without AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, csv, flash, air, adobe

I made a topotrainer in Flash. Now I wanted to export the data every time you run the topotrainer. So I have found out there is only one way to write lines in other files using actionscript:

```
var myFile:File = File.desktopDirectory;
myFile = myFile.resolvePath("TopoTrainerData.csv");
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(myFile, FileMode.APPEND);
stream.writeUTFBytes(TryCounter + "," + DateToday + "," + "\n");
stream.close();
```

This code works perfectly in my project now, but it uses the methods `FileStream`, `File` and `FileMode` which are only applicable if you make your file an AIR file in stead of a flash player. The problem than is that I can not open the swf file anymore. So I can't run the program in full screen desktop mode.

Is there any other way to save your variables into a .csv file? Through another application/language?

I have been looking for hours on the internet now for a solution, hope you guys can help me in some way,

Justin van Til

Comment: When I try to open the swf file (by double clicking), just nothing happens. Maybe it is because I made the project in Flash and changed it to AIR at the end to save the data?

Comment: Hmm, but I have no errors in my file after I run it as AIR.

Comment: I manage to run the converted swf file with AIR settings perfectly untill I enter this line:"var myFile:File = File.desktopDirectory;". Than I cannot open the swf anymore... Any idea?

Comment: Well not converting really. After changing publish settings to AIR in stead of Flash player, is what I meant.

Comment: Flash player has no built in classes for operating with file-system, thats why swf built for AIR wont work properly in Flash Player. Standalone swf can not write files to disk. Consider converting application to AIR, or use SharedObject instead of filesystem.